# unable to connect power bi to python

Tags: python, powerbi, anaconda, spyder

Unable to connect power bi to python
Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error.
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\Data sets for sessions\Module-1 assginment\data sets for sessions'
"
this is the error that has shown after writing the python script

new base has been created in anaconda navigator

Comment: See [MRE] guidelines. We need enough information to cause the problem ourselves -- and to know exactly which line caused the error (which a full stack trace will show) and the ownership and permissions relevant to the stated error (if your service genuinely can't access the file, then _of course_ it's going to get this error).